# Uniform random variables question

Tags: probability, solution-verification, uniform-distribution

Let U and V be independent random variables, both uniformly distributed on [0, 1]. Find
the probability that the quadratic equation $x^
2 + 2Ux + V = 0$ has two real solutions.

My solution:
The probability of two real solutions is the probability that $4U^2 - 4V > 0$.

$$
P(4U^2 - 4V > 0) = P(U^2>V)\\
=\int_{0}^{1} P(U^2>V|V=k)f_V(k)dk\\
=\int_{0}^{1} P(U>\sqrt{k})f_V(k)dk\\
=\int_{0}^{1} (1-\sqrt{k})f_V(k)dk\\
=\int_{0}^{1} (1-\sqrt{k}) dk
=\frac{1}{3}
$$
Does anyone see any problems with this?

Comment: $P[V=k]=0$ for all $k \in [0,1]$.  You mean $f_V(k)$. And I do not know how you get $1/10$.  [additional style issue: I would have conditioned on $V=v$ and written $f_V(v)dv$, instead of $V=k$ and $f_V(k)dk$]

Comment: I see your edits.  How do you get $f_V(k)=k$?  I see now that this leads to the $1/10$ value, but this is incorrect because $f_V(k)\neq k$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these mistakes - I've updated it again with $f_V(k) = 1$.

Comment: Yes, that looks good, now with the $1/3$ value.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way to compute $\Pr[U^2 > V]$ is to observe that in the unit square $(U,V) \in [0,1]^2$, the region for which $U^2 > V$ is satisfied is given by $$0 \le V < U^2 \le 1,$$ hence $$\Pr[U^2 > V] = \int_{u=0}^1 \int_{v=0}^{u^2} f_{U,V}(u,v) \, dv \, du = \int_{u=0}^1 u^2 \, du = \frac{1}{3}.$$  This is possible because the joint density of $U, V$ is uniform on the unit square.